# Pandas dataframe to AnguarJS

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, pandas

I have a RESTful architecture where AngularJS consumes DRF apis. Now with pandas, I converted my dataframe to html table but I can not figure out how to send it to AngularJS and render it. The dataframe table looks like this-

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe table">
<thead>
  <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th>2014-09-01</th>
    <th>2014-12-01</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1.460000</td>
     <td>7.100000</td>
     <td>17.5300</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

And so on, its a big table. Now either I can store this as unescaped in django but then how do I make AngularJS use it? Also, how to save it unescaped in django `textfield()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked without changing anything. Saved the dataframe to `textfiled()` after `.to_html`, serialized it with drf and used ng-sanitize in AngularJS and the tables rendered.

Comment: Can you explain it clearly? Currently, I have a dataframe and want to add angularjs attributes to rows(`td`'s)

Answer (score 2):

Would it not be easier to `pandas.DataFrame.to_json()` then render in AngluarJS? feels like the html step is adding complexity.

Comment: It has alot of `<td>`s and that's a lot of hardcode even with ng-repeat, also is a big table and with lots of headers makes it complex in AngularJS